# I am trying to login with Google Plus in Samsung tab. App not responding in my device but on emulator working fine

Tags: android

The Problem occurs..... Log cat is showing like that

```
6-22 13:13:46.992 5620-5649/app.demo.googleplusdemo W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 8298000 but found 4325032
06-22 13:13:47.000 5620-5620/app.demo.googleplusdemo D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
06-22 13:13:47.000 5620-5620/app.demo.googleplusdemo W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d36960)
06-22 13:13:47.000 5620-5620/app.demo.googleplusdemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at app.demo.googleplusdemo.MainActivity.onConnectionFailed(MainActivity.java:127)
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzk.zzl(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzmg.zze(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzme.zzi(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzme.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzme$zze$1.zzpc(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzmi$zza.zzd(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzmi$zzb.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Play services out of date... try updating play services on your phone
and 
also check the null point its expecting a value but its null so the app crashes